# Open and Close a menu with javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript, menu, onclick

I have a Menu that i used CSS to open on a hover but on a mobile that doesn't work so trying to also put a onclick on to it. have it open on the onclick but i cant close it. the postion i have the menu set at is -200 and then on a hover the position goes left to 0 which makes the menu slide out.
my javascript is

```
function openMenu(){
   document.getElementById('colorchanger').style.left = 0 + 'px'        
}
```

my HTML for that div is

```
<div id="colorchanger" onMouseDown="openMenu();">
```

I just want the menu to slide back to -200 onclick again.

Answer (score -1):

```
function openMenu(){
  var left=document.getElementById('colorchanger').style.getPropertyValue("left");
  if(left=='-200')
  {
    document.getElementById('colorchanger').style.left = 0 + 'px'
  }
  else
  {
     document.getElementById('colorchanger').style.left = -200 + 'px'
  }
}
```